# How to handle exception in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
postRetweet :: IO [TweetIdStr] -> IO [Status]
postRetweet tweetId = do
    let response1 = tweetId >>= \tweetId1 -> mapM (\tid -> (postWith authenticate (retweetUrl++tid++".json") (DB.pack "ABC"))  ) tweetId1
    response1 >>= \rid -> (mapM (\x -> pure (x^. responseStatus) ) rid)
```

the above code is to retweet a tweet based on the tweetId
i get an exception if retweeting of a single tweet fails. how to handle that?

using try i did it

```
postRetweet :: IO [TweetIdStr] -> IO [Status]
postRetweet tweetId = do
    tweetId >>= \tweetId1 -> (CM.foldM (\arr tid ->  ((try (postWith authenticate (retweetUrl++tid++".json") (DB.pack "ABC")) ):: IO (Either SomeException (Response BL.ByteString)) ) >>= 
         \sc ->
                case sc of
                    Right val ->   if (val ^. responseStatus ^. statusCode)==200
                                        then pure (arr++[val ^. responseStatus])  
                                    else pure (arr)              
                    Left x -> pure (arr) ) [] tweetId1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement exception handling with `try/catch` and/or build a type that can hold the possibility of an error, e.g. `IO (Either Error Result)`.

See: https://wiki.haskell.org/Handling_errors_in_Haskell